# How to start only one application on booting in RHEL 6?

Tags: rhel

I want to start only one application without any desktop after booting the system, it is like only application should be there not anything in RHEL 6.

Comment: Not even the application for bringing up the network?

Comment: Is this an X application or a terminal application?

Comment: @jasonwryan to do my requirement where i have to login, i.e. root or user mode?

Answer (score 1):

OP clarified in a comment that the idea is to launch the application on *login*, not on boot.

Look for `~/.xinitrc` (this file normally doesn't exist, X starts `/etc/X11/xinitrc` as a fallback here on Fedora, it might do differently on other distributions). That file determines what applications to start by default. Depending on the desktop environment configured for the account, other startup files could come into play.

Be careful, playing with this could lock the account out for good.

Comment: Starting an application as root-user after login? Sick... But RHEL6 should behave like Fedora.

Comment: @Nils, who said the user logging in and launching the application has to be root?

Comment: @vonbrand, Thank you for your reply. My doubt is in which i have to start application after login i.e. root mode or user mode.

Answer (score 0):

If your application has a proper init-script:
`chkconfig application on`

The default-runlevel can be set to 3 (multiuser without GUI).

Comment: Thank you Nils, my requirement is when i logged into system in the root/user mode it should display the application and nothing else. no desktop is required.